# Folder Permissions across servers

Tags: c#, permissions, directory, create-directory

I am trying to figure out what the reason behind this issue I am having, is. I am actually using a specific account to create folders in my c# POC application:

```
using (Impersonation.LogonUser(/*user credentials*/))
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(fullpath);
}
```

This works great when I run this app on a machine and I refer to one of the shares/folders on the same machine via an UNC path. So, If I run this app on *SERVER1* and my destination path is `\\Server1\test$\Root\[my new folder]`.
It works great as user that I am running it under, has permissions to create the folders.

But If I deploy this app to another server and from there If I try to hit the same UNC path on *SERVER1* that I used above, it gives me error:

> Access denied

Its' the same using statement and hence the same user. The folder path is the same except that I am hitting the path `\\Server1\test$\Root` from *SERVER2*. This server can "read" the folder meaning I can hit `\\Server1\test$\Root` when I am logged in on *SERVER2* but *CreateDirectory* seems to fail.

Can you please let me know what I could be doing wrong and what kind of special permissions are needed for me to access Root folder on *SERVER1* from *SERVER2*, though the user context is the same. Thanks.

Comment: Please, next time, try to put more effort in formatting your question. It is not so hard, and you more likely to get answer. Many experienced users here just rain blood from eyes when they see complex question without formatting.

Comment: So sorry about that. I can see why. I will make a conscious effort to format the question next time I ask. Thank You.